# Is there a way to query for the supported compatibility level of a SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

In the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017), we have a list of 'Supported Compatibility Level Values' for each SQL Server version. Is this information persisted in SQL Server? If not, is there any other way to fetch this information?

I looked at the Windows registry already, I did not find it.

Comment: I don't recall there being a DMV, no, but it's not something that will ever change with a released version of SQL server, so the documentation would seem to suffice.

Comment: @Larnu The concern is for the new sql server versions, I need to change my scripts for every new released version instead of fetching it dynamically.

Comment: The number of supported compatibility levels can be told by looking at the number of place holders in sys.messages for message id 15048 but unfortunately it doesn't have the values hardcoded

Comment: This is even more important, when you consider that queries such as AT TIME ZONE, will still work when a database compatibility is lower than when it's introduced. i.e. if the server is a higher version, but the database compatibility is set to lower, some statements introduced later STILL work. So maybe querying the master DB or combining with  select SERVERPROPERTY('Productversion'), or 'Edition' is required. Note: Azure Managed Instance reports product version 12 - which is moronic!

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft used to have an approach where each version of SQL Server supported the compatibility level of the current release down to n-2.

Since the release of SQL Server 2016, the previously supported compatibility levels have not been removed (this is intended to assist with the change to certification at the database compatibility level).  I'm not completely sure whether 100 will be removed in the next release of SQL Server, but I suspect that it will remain to assist with future upgrade paths.

There is a [matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) that shows this pattern.

What this effectively means is that you could query the master database to get the current release compatibility level and then assume that each release down to 100 is also available.

Answer (score 2):

Reasonable to assume tempdb will have compatibility level of engine ?

```
SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'tempdb';
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpfu and exactly what youre after

```
    select name, compatibility_level , version_name = 
    CASE compatibility_level
        WHEN 65  THEN 'SQL Server 6.5'
        WHEN 70  THEN 'SQL Server 7.0'
        WHEN 80  THEN 'SQL Server 2000'
        WHEN 90  THEN 'SQL Server 2005'
        WHEN 100 THEN 'SQL Server 2008/R2'
        WHEN 110 THEN 'SQL Server 2012'
        WHEN 120 THEN 'SQL Server 2014'
        WHEN 130 THEN 'SQL Server 2016'
        WHEN 140 THEN 'SQL Server 2017'
        WHEN 150 THEN 'SQL Server 2019'
        ELSE 'new unknown - '+CONVERT(varchar(10),compatibility_level)
    END
    from sys.databases
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query I use to get basic info on databases from a server. It queries [sys.databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). To translate the compatability level you can use this [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
SELECT
    name                     AS [DB Name]
    , state_desc             AS [Status]
    , create_date            AS [Create Date]
    , database_id            AS [DB ID]
    , recovery_model_desc    AS [Recovery Model]
    , SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) AS [Owner]
    , [compatibility_level]  AS [Compatibility Level]
    , collation_name         AS [Collation]
    , is_auto_close_on       AS [Auto Close]
FROM
    sys.databases
ORDER BY
    name;
```